# What is the difference between array like initializes and normal ones?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I recently saw some angular code which was like this

```
angular
    .module("MYController", function($scope) {}) // ...
```

and in my tutorial section we were taught to define is like this

```
angular
    .module("MYController", ["$scope", function($scope) {}]); // ...
```

my question is what is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from my previous answer,

> After minification the old code wouldn't have worked because of the
>   fact that when UglifyJS (or equivalent) minifies it, it renames the
>   reserved variables `$scope`, etc. to `e` `a` or something else, which
>   Angular is unable to resolve; when you use the array notation (I
>   forgot its specific name), angular knows what to inject (Because you are 
>   using array of String and String does not convert at minification time), 
>   only the names have changed.

You can read more about it http://toddmotto.com/angular-js-dependency-injection-annotation-process/

Comment: so it makes minification better?

Comment: Yes. In a way. Read that article, and you'll get to know.

Comment: Actually its not a kind of minification better. The main cause of minification is to decrease the size of downloadable JavaScript code to increase performance and loading time. Suppose you have written a code function myFunc(abc, xyz){abc+xyz}. Now at the time of minification myFunc will be changed to m, abc to a, xyz to x (Kind of that). So size of the file will get decrease. If same way angular code does this then $scope injection will be converted as s (kind of). So angular will not understand it is $scope of other. But if you use array of some strings, Since string does not change it work